# When these prototype devices become commercialised/productionised, how is the signal processing aspect of the oscilloscope built in to the device?

Tags: oscilloscope, signal-processing, sampling, bandwidth, production

I read a lot of research papers that use large and expensive equipment, such as oscilloscopes, to do their signal processing. Oscilloscopes offer high sampling rate and bandwidth, which makes them good for signal processing applications. Also, nearly all of these research papers involve work in a lab (bench-top work), so the convenience benefit of using an oscilloscope, rather than designing, and having manufactured, a custom PCB, is clear. However, when it comes to commercialised/production devices, we often require serious signal processing to be done (that is, signal processing requiring significant sampling rate and bandwidth), and yet, these devices obviously do not have built-in lab oscilloscopes (and such a thing wouldn't be economical, anyway). So, when these prototype devices become commercialised/productionised, how is this signal processing aspect of the oscilloscope built in to the device? The [Digilent Analog Discovery](https://store.digilentinc.com/analog-discovery-2-100msps-usb-oscilloscope-logic-analyzer-and-variable-power-supply/) seems like a more modular device, but even it seems too expensive (and too large) to include in a lot of commercial devices that require serious signal processing. All of my study has been on the lab/prototype/research aspect, so I'm trying to understand how things work on the production/commercialisation side of things.

Comment: For smaller volume parts they typically buy a commerical PC digitizer, usually over PCIe. For large volume you design one yourself to avoid paying markup.

Comment: @user1850479 What is a "PC digitizer"?

Comment: An analog to digital converter, some memory, an interface to some kind of PC bus such as PCIe and a driver for windows/Linux.

Comment: @user1850479 Hmm interesting. So are these the things that require "RF circuit design" to build?

Comment: If you want to sample RF frequencies then yes you would need some RF design.  For lower frequencies, not so much.  More challenging is usually the digital design for the interface between the PC and the A/D converter.  Is this your whole question?  Should I write up an answer?

Comment: @user1850479 If these "PC digitizers" are how the signal processing job of the oscilloscope is done in commercial/production devices, then yes, that was pretty much my question. I would like to learn how to custom-build such a device for my own work, so that's where this question is coming from. It would need to be as "high performance" (high sampling rate and bandwidth) as possible (that's where I heard about the "RF circuit design" stuff), but constrained to reasonable cost. The Digilent Analog Discovery seemed relevant, so that's why I mentioned it.

Comment: What sampling rate and how many bits do you require?  This will have a profound impact on what you need to do.  Edit this information into your question.

Comment: @user1850479 I don't know such precise details yet. At the moment, I'm just trying to learn this more generally, and then I'll optimise based on precise details later when I know more. But I'd say the specs of the Digilent device I linked seem like a good starting point.

Comment: I'm voting to close this then until you get it into a state where it is focused enough to be answerable.  In the meantime, I suggest reading through various related questions.  Getting analog data onto a digital system is a common enough problem, looking through previous work may help you narrow down your problem into something more tractable.

Comment: @user1850479 is there a specific reference you would recommend? Should I perhaps start with a RF circuit design textbook? I’d like to start by building a device like the Digilent one (that is, with the same specs).

Comment: What;s wrong with using ADCs and FPGAs or DSPs? Oscilloscopes are built with the knowledge that they might measure many things. A production device will only do one thing so can be made much smaller, and it doesn't need a screen, knobs, or even general purpose inputs or probes. I don't think it is really thought of as "building an oscilloscope into the device" as much as building an analog front-end and a digital processing back end.

Comment: @DKNguyen Yes, that's my point. I'm not interested in building another oscilloscope; rather, I want to build "low-cost", "high-performance" (for my application) electronics that are specific to my application – it just has to do *the same "thing"* as the oscilloscope does (based on the answer from rfdave, I think that "thing" is a "signal digitizer"). As I mentioned, I would like to start by building a lower cost, custom version of the Digilent device I linked in my question.

Comment: So it sounds like you want this: https://www.analog.com/en/education/education-library/mixed_signal_dsp_design_book.html and this https://www.analog.com/en/education/education-library/linear-circuit-design-handbook.html. Good luck drinking from the fire hose.

Comment: @DKNguyen Hmm, yes, that looks like it might be it. It looks like I have a lot of work to do. :) Thanks!

Comment: Signal Conditioning (Filters, amps, etc.) -> ADC -> MCU/FPGA/DSP -> (?) Math Voodoo (?) -> Result

Comment: I pulled apart a tek scope once, they have a few FPGA's and custom ASICs amongst other things. This is also a good vid: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VFX47ZGOn_o However, this question is off topic because it isn't focused enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, an Oscilloscope isn't doing much in the way of signal processing, instead it's probably serving as a signal digitizer, with the digitized signal feeding into a signal processing application running on a computer. What you use to implement this in "production" will depend significantly on the "Significant Sampling Rate and Bandwidth" and the signal processing algorithms you need to run. if you need to sample at multiGHz rates, with significant bandwidth, then you'll also have significant computational requirements driven by Gbit/sec datarates. Generally, systems like that would require a large, fast, FPGA to ingest the data and run the signal processing application needed.

Systems like 5GNR (mmWave extension of 5G Cellular) would start with something like that, and then, as the requirements firm up, the design would be implemented in a handful of ASICs (Application Specific Integrated Circuits) to achieve minimium size/cost/power.

If you need to operate below 6 GHz, then Software Defined Radios such as the Ettus N310 might work well, in conjunction with GNURadio for the signal processsing bits.

In other words, you're getting the Canonical engineering answer to a question "It Depends on the details"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if I wanted to build something with the specs of the Digilent device? Where would I start to learn about this?

Comment: A starting point would be to look for a teardown of the Digilent device, and start researching what that components that uses. That uses an analog devices AD9648 as the ADC, so starting with reading the datasheet as well as the application notes that are available. This will help you understand what is going on inside the Analog Discovery 2. Using that, you can start extending your knowledge, and asking more focused questions.

Comment: Yes, I'll start researching that. DKNguyen recommended https://www.analog.com/en/education/education-library/mixed_signal_dsp_design_book.html and https://www.analog.com/en/education/education-library/linear-circuit-design-handbook.html in his comment, so I'll also start studying these. Thanks for the help!

Comment: And for the "logic" part, there is this one : http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Open_Bench_Logic_Sniffer